Authenticate GCP client library from SPA via the IAP credentials
I currently have a React app hosted in Cloud Run behind an IAP which is working great. I would like to add support for the React app to upload files to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket. I would like to leverage the already authenticated user via the IAP login to automatically authenticate the GCS client library and enforce permissions via GCP IAM policies. My question is how to get the auth token from the JavaScript React app to authenticate the GCS client library? I see a cookie is set via IAP but it's an http only cookie and thus cannot be accessed via JavaScript.

I'm pretty sure it won't work but you can try to add the storage object creator role to the SA: service-[PROJECT-NUMBER]@gcp-sa-iap.iam.gserviceaccount.com. But I never saw that IAP was compliant with Cloud Storage, so... The other solution is to have an endpoint in your Cloud Run service that generate a signedURL and the client use it to upload the file. It's a cleaner pattern.

Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, I think I'm going to go that route. I spent a good amount of time trying to add new scopes to the IAP flow and leveraging that to get an OAuth access token. This doesn't seem possible which is frustrating as it would make IAP much more useful but the signed URL will work for the time being.
